# Javascript to toggle background image fails to display in IE7

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7, background-image

I'm doing on [this template](http://checkintonight.freeiz.com/) recently. The background images works fine in all browsers except in IE7. According to some googling, I have removed the '' sign from the url of those images. However, I can't get it done either.
[image]

Here is my [JavaScript link](http://checkintonight.freeiz.com/js/custom-form-elements.js).

I spend days for finding this bug. Could anyone have any idea to figure out this?

Comment: I went through a bit of the javascript and didn't see anything obvious... I'd really suggest you use classes to style your checkboxes and others. It will make everything easier and you won't have to worry about crossbrowser style manipulation which can be an hassle.

Another option to make your life easy would be to use jQuery, if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see the problem comes from your inline spans that have no content.

I'm using IE9 in IE7 mode, and I don't see your checkboxes at all. However, I added `display:block` to one of them, and it appeared and background switched on click.

So I suggest you to try implement them as floating divs instead of spans. Or at least make sure your spans have content and aren't rendered as 0x0 elements.